# [DateTime]::ParseExact throws exception

Tags: powershell

`$dateParse = [datetime]::ParseExact("5/‎14/‎2008 ‏‎1:57", "M/d/yyyy h:m", $null)`

results in

```
MethodInvocationException: C:\Users\89pmo\source\repos\File2Folder\RenameFile.ps1:9:3
Line |
   9 |          $dateParse = [datetime]::ParseExact("5/‎14/‎2008 ‏‎1:57", "M/ …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String '5/‎14/‎2008 ‏‎1:57' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

I have also tried with `M/d/yyyy h:mm`, `M/dd/yyyy h:m`, and `M/dd/yyyy h:mm` to no avail..

Comment: I've also tried `$dateParse = [datetime]::ParseExact("5/‎14/‎2008 ‏‎1:57 am", "M/d/yyyy h:m tt", $null)` thinking it was a am/pm error. That did not work either.

Comment: Wicked. When I copied and pasted your code into my console, I got unreadable extra characters. My code page is ANSI. Once they were deleted, the parse worked for me. `[datetime]::ParseExact("5/?14/?2008 ??1:57", "M/d/yyyy h:m", $null)` is what I saw.

Comment: For me, this works `[datetime]::ParseExact("10/20/2020 5:30 am", "M/d/yyyy H:m tt", $null)`
but this does not `[datetime]::ParseExact("10/20/2020 5:30 pm", "M/d/yyyy H:m tt", $null)`

Comment: The only difference being am vs pm

Comment: if you are using `H` (24 hour variant), then there's no need for AM or PM. If using `h` (the 12 hour variant), then you would. `AM` works because `5` is the same hour number in 24 or 12 hour variants.

Comment: Gah... you are right. Ok so I have extra hidden char in my string input, and just need to be careful with my H vs h

Comment: If you want to create an answer for the extra chars bit, I'll mark it correct. That seems to be the real underlying issue besides my carelessness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When copying and pasting your code into my console, I noticed extra unreadable characters (for ASCII anyway). Once those extra characters were removed, the original parsing worked.

```
# Original display in console
$dateParse = [datetime]::ParseExact("5/?14/?2008 ??1:57", "M/d/yyyy h:m", $null)
# This worked
$dateParse = [datetime]::ParseExact("5/14/2008 1:57", "M/d/yyyy h:m", $null)
```

Regarding including `AM` and `PM` in times, you will need to stick with `h` (12-hour format variant) for hours.